# Passing string to anonymous object to Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Usage of my tag helper:

```
<website-information info="new WebInfo { Age = 55, Author = "Test" }"></website-information>
```

How to pass Author string property correctly? When I write Author = " it thinks that the info attribute should look like this:

```
new WebInfo { Age = 55, Author = "
```

I got compilation error

Answer (score 2):

Razor allow us to use `@` to evaluate C# expression. So you could use `@` to get an complex object.

As for your scenario, you could simply use the following code:

```cs
<website-information info='@(new WebInfo{Age=22,Author="author1"})'></website-information>

<website-information info="@(new WebInfo{Age=33,Author="author2"})"></website-information>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just throw in a complex object.  Depending on how exactly you want the output to look like on the client side, let's say:

```
<website-information info="Age:55,Author:Test"></website-information>
```

Then you would do this:

```
<website-information info="@("Age:55,Author:Test")"></website-information>
```

or:

```
@{
   var webInfo = new WebInfo { Age = 55, Author = "Test" };

   <website-information info="@("Age:" + webInfo.Age + ",Author:" + webInfo.Author)"></website-information>

}
```